# How to navigate from somewhere out of Navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, onesignal

> Navigator.js

```js
const App = createStackNavigator({
  screenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  screenB: { screen: ScreenB }
})

const Navigator = createAppContainer(App);

export default Navigator;
```

> App.js

```js
return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MainNavigator />
    </Provider>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

Code above is how I've configured React-Navigation V3. On `App.js`, it also subscribe to push notification events as below

```js
componentDidMount() {
  OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
}

onOpened = ({ notification }) => {
  //How to navigate to screenB?
}
```

So my question is, how the subscribed event can navigate user to certain screen since `App.js` is not wrapped by `MainNavigator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use onesignal inside your navigator. It will work as expected.
But, in your question you asked a way to navigate outside the navigator. here is a dummy code to do that.

```
        <Navigation ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
```

get the reference of your navgation, `this.navigator` would have many properties. including the navigation.

then you could do something like,

```
goToSomething = () => {

 console.log(this.navigator); //check all the methods it has
 this.navigator._navigation.navigate('Something');
 // NOTE: here it is _navigation, not navigation
}

  <Navigation ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
<YourComponent goToSomething={this.goToSomething}/>
```

and I see you have used `onesignal`, so this won't be needed. use the listeners in your first screen.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `NavigationService` ref.

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

const TopLevelNavigator = createStackNavigator({ /* ... */ })

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

See more here: [Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html).

Alternatively, you could just move down the subscription to push notifications down one level.